# Составить mysql запрос

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, есть 2 таблички. Первая с моделями, для простоты пусть будет 2 поля: id, name
И табличка связей моделей с видео с полями: id, model_id, video_id
Подскажите как вывести моделей, у которых есть хотя бы одно видео

Comment: покажи структуру таблицы

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT model.id, model.name, COUNT(vm.id) as video_count FROM video_model as vm LEFT JOIN model ON vm.model_id=model.od GROUP BY model.id HAVING video_count>0
```